# Badge Suggestion for Site Specific Blogs

Tags: discussion, badge-request, blog-overflow

So I'm watching the blog on [cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) try to get off the ground.  Could you create a set of badges for posting stories in the site-specific blog?

- **[Fresh Ink]** First accepted blog post
- **[Quick Quill]** 20 accepted blog posts
- **[Iron Pen]** 50 accepted blog posts

Implicit in this request is *my desire* for a more automated blog submission mechanism, as Stack Exchange runs Blog Overflow ... hopefully this wouldn't be impossible someday.  But in the mean time, perhaps just noting which users **contributed** to a given blog post and then awarding it to the site-specific linked account.

Comment: +1 Seems technically possible, being a WP database, and encourages good behavior that isn't already rewarded in some form.

Comment: What does [cross-validated] refer to?

Comment: [cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) is another stack exchange site dedicated to statistical questions.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought they weren't allowing individually named Stack Exchange sites.  They stopped that when they changed WebApps.

Answer (score 6):

The site and the blog are completely separate systems.  The blogs are a WordPress install, nothing custom that we've written.

There is no connection between someone's account on the blog and their account on the site, or vice versa.  This makes it currently impossible to connect badges because there's no way we could dynamically determine how to award the badges to who and there is no manual awarding of badges.

Comment: Drat.  I was really hoping.  Perhaps an extra DB entry to link the users and join across queries??  Not the sort of thing that would need to run more than once a week or even once a month.

Comment: We'd need some way to tie in authentication to make sure the account is the same person on each site.  At this time, I have absolutely no idea how feasible that'd be.

Comment: oh crap. Authentication.  Nevermind.  I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I'm happy to be corrected and told there'd be a way.  If there's a decent way to do it, I'm not against investigating.

Comment: Perhaps asking on the [WP site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) is the way to go?

Comment: @rebecca it isn't impossible, but it would be awkward. We *do* have loosely coupled badges like Precognitive and Talkative but they are to other websites we coded and 100% control. WordPress is pretty flexible, but we didn't write it..

Comment: For authentication, I think it would be possible to merge the accounts and keep everything consistent from the exchange to blogoverflow [using OpenID](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15).  *I think could work*, but I really don't *know* -- I personally only setup a MovableType blog which, should you ever want to switch, MT does support OpenID authentication [out of the box](http://www.movabletype.com/blog/2007/09/openid-built-in-with-mt4.html).

Comment: What would be nice is if _someday_ Stack Exchange wrote their own blogging platform. They already wrote their own chat platform, so it's not _inconceivable_, but I'm certainly not expecting to see it anytime soon.